# table first column

Tags: tables

I want to create a table, like that:

[image]

But, I want more space in first column. How I could resolve this problem ?

My code is:

```
    \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
  \toprule
          & Clay  & Talco & GCC   & PCC \\
    \midrule
    Formula &       &       &       &  \\
    Estrutura do cristal & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & dfgdg \\
    Densidade ($kg/dm^3$) & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Índice de Refracção & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Dureza (escala de Mohs) & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Brancura (\%) & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Distribuição de Tamanhos (\%) & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    < 10 um & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    <5 um & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    <2    & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    àrea de superficie & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Potencial Zeta & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Abrasão & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Why do you think you need `tabularx`? There's no reason for a table to be as wide as the line length and there are reasons not to. I'd go for a simple tabular with `{lcccc}`.

Answer (score 1):

use only for the first column the type `X`:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\Centering}X *4c}
```

I also used package `ragged2e`. It allows only to write `\Centering`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\Centering}X *4c}
  \toprule
          & Clay  & Talco & GCC   & PCC \\
    \midrule
    Formula &       &       &       &  \\
    Estrutura do cristal & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & dfgdg \\
    Densidade ($kg/dm^3$) & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Índice de Refracção & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Dureza (escala de Mohs) & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Brancura (\%) & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Distribuição de Tamanhos (\%) & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    < 10 um & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    <5 um & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    <2    & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    àrea de superficie & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Potencial Zeta & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
    Abrasão & vdfvd & fdgfd & fdgfd & fdgfd \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

To save some space you can also use:

```
  {\small\tabcolsep=3pt
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\Centering}X *4c @{}}
  ...
  \end{tabularx}%
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain me more details about ragged2e package ?

Comment: this code don't work :s

Comment: It allows hyphenation with `\Centering`, `RaggedRight`, and `RagggedLeft`.

Comment: "this code don't work" is not a useful comment ...